# Can an unoptimize dedup job be resumed?

Tags: windows-server-2016, deduplication

I have a `Start-DedupJob -type Unoptimize ...` that's been running for 7 hours and is still at 0% progress.

I'm reconfiguring the server and need to restart.

Disk activity has been pegged to near capacity, with reading and writing often over a hundred MB/sec.

I'm not sure what it's doing, but can I restart without losing the 7 hours of work done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can absolutely cancel what you're doing with Stop-DedupJob and next time you'll start "Unoptimize" process it will proceed from where it stopped now. Bad news are with low disk activity and 0% complete I'm pretty sure scrubbing/ deoptimization process is stuck and didn't actually done anything...

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/deduplication/stop-dedupjob

TL;DR: Fastest and flawless way to get rid of a deduplication is to...

a) Backup your volume with something like Veeam
b) Run verification/ sandbox to make sure your data integrity is OK
b) Re-format original disk
c) Get data back from backup created in a)

Good luck!

Comment: Yes, expirienced the same Issues. DeDedupe seems to be bugged, guess to few people are actually trying to do this. Also used VEEAMs daily backup to "dededupe", took an hour vs watching the dedupe job sitting @ 0% for several days.